# How do i download python and how to set it up in the best way possible?

Tags: python

im very new to python and coding and i dont know from where to start, how do i download python wich version and what platform to use. i got a lot of recommandations , but i came here to get more of a overlook about everything i need to use

any help would be much appreciated, and thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the best place for this sort of question. Try instead: https://reddit.com/r/learnpython.

Comment: @costaparas i tried its just that people didint help me at all

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is opinion based. We even do not know what your problem is. If you want to know how to start using python: https://www.python.org/ is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so regarding your question, i will answer them 1 by 1:

1- wich version of python dont really matyter as long that you are a beginner and you are not using any library, as that said i highly suggest that you download python 3.9 (dosent matter wich one wether 3.9.1 or 3.9.0) here is the download link for it :
https://www.python.org/downloads/

Try checking out a video about how to setup python properly and how to avoid errors( for example dont forget to check the checkbox when add to path appears)

2- when it comes to beginner freidly platforms i highly suggest you to use vs code (Visual Studio code ) here is the download link to it : https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Hopefully this helped you and good luck with your coding :)

Comment: no worries, if you need any other help feel free to ask